# Should I avoid overriding a rails model method when possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

More specifically, if I have two options: do a check in the controller or override an [association method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference) in the model, which one should I prefer?

Edit:

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author

  def author
    super || build_author
  end
end
```

Is the code above ok or should I prefer another solution like the one below?

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def update
    set_author
    if @book.update_attributes(params[:book])
      #redirect
    else
      #render show page - unprocessable entity
    end
  end

  def set_author
    a = Author.where(fields)
    @book.author = a || @book.build_author
  end
end
```

Comment: Why is this a binary choice?  I would normally put business logic in the model.  If it is appropriate to do the check in the model, why can't you write a method that makes use of the model's association method without overriding that method?  Anyway, I am not sure you have a binary choice here.  I cannot really advise you unless I see the code for your model and controller.

Comment: Convention is to have business logic in the model but then as a developer we need to decide what is the best place for a piece of code.. no point in creating additional model methods if controller or view can simplify the code..

Comment: As a general rule, I would discourage overriding association methods in the model.  Doing could make the code brittle and less maintainable.  Rails follows the "convention over configuration" philosophy, so Rails developers expect models to behave in a certain ways.  Changing that behavior could make it difficult on the people who maintain the code in the future.  There may be good reasons for overriding, but if you do, be sure to document the change and perhaps explain your rationale.

Comment: I will prefer to keep it in the controller because keeping it in the model can have implications in other parts of the code will this change is not required. Also your controller set_author method should be     `@book.author  || @book.build_author`